# How do I prevent rmarkdown tables from moving to the centre or the RHS?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

For some reason my table does not remain on the left hand side when I knit even when I have `position = "left"`, please see screenshot examples below:

[image]

The code I used:

```
df %>% 
  tabyl(edinburgh_postnatal_depression_scale_epds_enrolmen_complete, show_na=FALSE) %>%  
  rename(" " = "edinburgh_postnatal_depression_scale_epds_enrolmen_complete", "Freq" = "n", "%" = "percent") %>%
   adorn_totals("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(affix_sign = FALSE) %>% 
  knitr::kable(
    format = "latex",
    align = "l",
    linesep = "") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
      position = "left",
      latex_options = c("striped", "repeat_header", "HOLD_position"),
      stripe_color = "gray!15") %>% 
      row_spec(0, bold = TRUE)
```

This code remains the same for all my table but somehow some of them move to the centre or to the RHS.

Comment: Please don’t use images of code as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Try using "HOLD_position" in the call to `latex_options`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I added the code instead. This unfortunately did not work

Comment: Without a reproducible example i.e. an extract from the rmarkdown document including text, code chunks  and at least a couple of tables with data it's hard to guess what might be the problem. The data can be dummy data just to illustrate the problem. This would be required to test possible solutions.